# HTML and CSS version used in VS 2008

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, html

I am currently using VS 2008 and Asp.net 3.5 with the basic tool kit provided.

What i want to know is the version of CSS and HTML that it uses.

I was going through HTML 5 is it possible to use it and the latest CSS version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/11/18/html-5-intellisense-and-validation-schema-for-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-web-developer.aspx